# Ruby hash - cannot loop data

Tags: ruby, loops, hash, each

I have this structure of data in a hash:

```
[{"name"=>"Peter", "surname"=>"Green"}, {"name"=>"Jane", "surname"=>"Miller"}]
```

But when I try to work with this hash, for example:

```
puts hash.count # returns nothing
hash.each do |data|
  puts data.name # => undefined method `name' for #<Hash:0x00000104bcf9f8>
end
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array#count` without an argument should return the number of elements, but it is more natural to use `length` or `size`. And `Hash` does not have a method `name`.

```
puts hash.length
hash.each do |data|
  puts data["name"]
end
```

By the way, what you refer to as `hash` is actually an array, and is confusing.